# Laravel listener subscribe to all events

Tags: laravel-5

I know that I can put a list of all the events but it's just stupid.

```
public function subscribe($events)
{
    $events->listen(
        'App\Events\UserLoggedIn',
        'App\Listeners\UserEventListener@onUserLogin'
    );

    $events->listen(
        'App\Events\UserLoggedOut',
        'App\Listeners\UserEventListener@onUserLogout'
    );
}
```

I'd like to use some sort of wildcart. Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events#registering-events-and-listeners
see Wildcard Event Listeners

```
$events->listen('event.*', function (array $data) {
//
});
```